# Facebook as tab scroll bars -- still no luck

Tags: facebook, tabs, scrollbar

I am really struggling with how to get the scroll bars off of my tab. I am simply trying to create a Facebook tab for a company Facebook page and I have tried everything to get the vertical scroll to go away. Here is the code I am working with

```
     <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="facebookstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.innerfade.js"></script>





<fb:share-button type="icon_link" class="url"></fb:share-button>



</head>


<body>

<table>

CONTENT

</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p><div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({appId: '{{277868305571181}}', status: true, cookie: true,xfbml: true});

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        FB.Canvas.setSize({height:1500});
    }, 250);

  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you set your **Canvas Height** to Settable in your [app advanced settings](http://developers.facebook.com/apps)?

Comment: you have a share button in the head?  Try removing the share button and adding FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(); instead of setSize.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to enable OAuth2 in your application settings.

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.init({
appId: '277868305571181',
 status: true, 
cookie: true,
xfbml: true,
oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
});    
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
    </script>
```